# Passing scroll events only to an obscured view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, event-handling

My iOS app has a scroll view containing text fields and buttons etc (a bit over 1000 points high) which are filled in and ultimately uploaded to a remote server.  After a successful upload, I want the user to be able to see their data, but not change it, or play with any of the buttons, sliders etc on the page.  The easy way to do this seems to be to "overlay" the view with a low alpha view which traps all touches while suggesting the page data and controls are "disabled".  This works, but I'd like the user to still be able to scroll the overlaid view to see all the fields.  Is there some way to detect, filter, and forward selected gestures from the outer view to the "covered" scroll view, or is there a quick way to disable all fields and controls in a view, apart from hitting each individually?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can disable all the labels etc by saying something like

```
Yourlabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

The best way is to put them all in an array and loop trough the array and call that on all the subviews. Either that or have a function that explicitly calls that on every element.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up with something very like that.